# H2 Class not found exception with JDBI

Tags: java, maven, h2, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm trying to set up a connection to an H2 database so I can keep testing my app.  The app uses `JDBI` instead of `JDBC`.  So far, every time I've run the app, I've received a Class not found error:

```
Causing: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: org.h2.Driver; from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@644d46;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@644d46
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56)
! at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:272)
! ... 22 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.h2.Driver; from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@644d46;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@644d46
```

I've set the path to the jar file in my environmental PATH variable, and set the `h2` jar as a dependency in the Project Structure (this is `Intellij`).  I've also imported the dependency in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As I'm using `JDBI`, I've also set up the `config.yml` file as such:

```
database:
  driverClass: org.h2.Driver;
  url: jdbc:h2://localhost:8082;
  user: username
```

None of this has had any affect.

Comment: Check if you run the code from `test` classes, not from `src/main`.

Comment: Are you bundling it properly. Could you please update post with `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; apparently, the semi-colon at the end of driverClass was causing the error.  Sorry for the trouble.